# Definir data para 7 dias/uma semana atrás

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de obter a data de hoje, e subtraí-la 7 dias. Lembrando que, se estivermos no dia 2 por exemplo, deverá subtrair 1 do mês. O mesmo se aplica ao ano.

Infelizmente, só achei exemplos que setam pra um dia específico, e não subtrair um n de dias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obter data de há uma semana/mês/ano atrás:

```
var uma_semana = new Date();
uma_semana.setDate(uma_semana.getDate() - 7);

var um_mes = new Date();
um_mes.setMonth(um_mes.getMonth() - 1);

var um_ano = new Date();
um_ano.setFullYear(um_ano.getFullYear() - 1);

console.log(uma_semana);
console.log(um_mes);
console.log(um_ano);
```

Comment: `um_mes.getDate() - 30` e `um_ano.getDate() - 365` não é perfeito. Há meses e anos com durações diferentes.

Comment: Tem toda razão, pensei que fosse a data de há 30 dias atrás. Vou corrigir